# Doesn't Closure on Promise Work With Asynchronously Affected Value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, closures, es6-promise

On the second then method there is a closed value(string), and I'm running setTimeout to change it after 1 second.
Also I'm returnin new Promise to resolved with setTimeout after 2 second to the value I'm changing with the previous setTimeout.
But after it resolved next then method logs out the value that is not affected by previous setTimeout.
Shouldn't I get 'foobarbaz' from the last then method's log.

Thanks in advance...

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('foo');
});
p1.then(function(string) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      string += 'bar';
      res(string);
    }, 2000);
  });
})
.then(function(string) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    string += 'baz';
    console.log(string);
  }, 1000);
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, string));
})
.then(function(string) {
  console.log(string);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is:

```
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, string));
```

This results in `setTimeout` getting an argument of what is *currently* in the `string` variable at the moment that line is run - although `string` gets reassigned in the upper `setTimeout`, that `setTimeout` hasn't run yet, so `string` remains `foobar`.

Similarly:

```js
let a = 'foo';
setTimeout(console.log, 200, a);
a = 'bar';
```

results in `foo` being logged, not `bar`.

If you pass a function that, when called, references what `string` is bound to *when said function is called*, results will be as expected:

```
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
  resolve(string);
}, 2000));
```

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('foo');
});
p1.then(function(string) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      string += 'bar';
      res(string);
    }, 2000);
  });
})
.then(function(string) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    string += 'baz';
    console.log(string);
  }, 1000);
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(string);
  }, 2000));
})
.then(function(string) {
  console.log(string);
});
```

Comment: thank you, your snippet is working. But I couldn't understand the difference between the your setTimeout and mine. 
Both are setting a function to run later in time, and yours is just passing the argument in the function, mine is passing as a third argument. Where is the different result coming from exactly?
Thank you...

Comment: Yours is passing the `string` *immediately*, when you're calling `setTimeout` (before it's been changed), so `setTimeout`'s internals call the callback with the value of the 3rd argument, which is `foobar`. Mine is *referencing* `string` again, after it's been changed to `foobarbaz` - it's not an argument, it's just referencing the outer variable name.

Comment: There is a closure in the *upper* `setTimeout`, but not in the lower one (at least, not one that's publicly visible)

Comment: Thank you, so when we pass it as a third argument to setTimeout, it won't reflect any value change in closure, well that means there is no closure whatsoever at that point if I'm correct? 
We are just passing is just a simple value what that argument refers to. 
But on the other case the argument passed the resolve to be called later is creating closure, it is not just a simply passed value, the reference is still on?
Thanks you...
(I deleted the before comment before you answered, sorry for misconnection)

Comment: Pretty much. If you had passed an object instead which got *mutated*, the mutation could be observed